# SeLinux, php/apache, clamd log

Tags: php, linux, selinux

I have an issue with clamd and I dont really know what to do with it, spend days trying to understand how SELinux works

clamd is currently writing its log to `/var/log/clamav/clamd.log`

my php/apache is trying to fopen that log but is getting a permission error due to SELinux

SELinux says the log se type is running under `var_log_t`

I change it to `httpd_sys_rw_content_t` and php/apache can open it fine but now clamd cannot start because it cannot append to the log file.

Is there a permission for SELinux that will allow both clamd AND apache to read/write to the log file?

Unfortunately due to circumstance I am not allowed to disable SELinux into permissive mode but I would be happy with a "SELinux ignore this file completly" option?

I know this is more of an SELinux question but I don't know if anyone here has come across the issue and solved it?

Comment: I think is a linux question. I would try changing the file's group maybe creating one, and put apache in this group.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.